# Grails request.getFile works in Jetty but returns Null when deployed to Glassfish 3.1.2 server

Tags: grails, groovy, glassfish, jetty

I built my app using Grails 2.0.4 and tested it in Jetty. In Jetty everything works fine, but when I deploy to Glassfish I get an npe when trying to assign a file in my action. Why would uploadedFile be null on glassfish but ok using jetty?

```
def  uploadedFile = request.getFile('name_of_file')
```

Firebug shows that the http request is getting the file. Here is the beginning of the multipart form data Post request from Firebug:

```
**name_of_file**    %PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 5 0 obj <</Length 2712/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream x[]oÜ6}_A /ÛÝZD}öM+¶ñÌT#'5¶ÂuÄeolÅþüÔ¥D^êòÑ(PÏuyÎ¹<¤4²úuuÚ¬|æ!k>®ÊfõëêëÊ÷|ÆìïUÈ~ÿñ
```

Thus it looks like the file information is being paramaterized on the client side when deployed but is not making it into the controller.

**My controller code:**

```
 def sample(){

    if (params.ID == null) return 

    def sampleInstance = new Sample(params)// new sample
    if (sampleInstance.validate()) { // try to validate
        def  uploadedFile = request.getFile('name_of_file')// see if there is a file to upload
        session.uploadedFile = [
            originalFile: uploadedFile.originalFilename
        ]



        if (uploadedFile != null) { // is there a file? 
            sampleInstance.filepath =${uploadedFile.originalFilename}" // save the original filename

        }
        if (params.ageUnk){
           sampleInstance.sampleAge = null;
        }
        if (!params.ageUnk){
        def patients_age_in_years = (Integer.parseInt(params.patientYrs) * 12)

        def patients_age_in_months = Integer.parseInt(params.patientMos)

        def patients_total_age_in_months = (patients_age_in_years + patients_age_in_months) 

        sampleInstance.sampleAge = patients_total_age_in_months
        }

        sampleInstance.enteredby = springSecurityService.currentUser.id 
        sampleInstance.save()// save the sample in the database

        redirect( action:'sample', model:[sampleInstance:sampleInstance, checkDate:today, date: now])

    }else{
         [sampleInstance:sampleInstance, checkDate:today, date: now]
    }

}
```

All paramaters are able to pass through except for the file. **Here is my gsp form:**

```
<g:uploadForm action="sample">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><br><b> Comments: &nbsp</b></td>
    <td><br><g:textField name="nameComments" value="" style='width: 200px'/></td>
  </tr>
    <td align="right"><br><b>ID: &nbsp</b></td>
    <td><br><g:textField name="nameID" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><br><b>Upload File: &nbsp</b></td>
    <td><br><input type='file' name='name_of_file' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td><g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table> 

</g:uploadForm>
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'originalFilename' on null object 
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:156) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:44) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227) 
at lims.SubmitSampleController.sample(SubmitSampleController.groovy:27) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:67) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:330) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:211) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:177) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:116) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:325) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:807) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:312) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:277) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:268) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:209) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:200) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:151) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369) 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) 
at org.apache.catalina.
```

Comment: You seem to be closing a `</table>` before you are closing the `<g:uploadForm>`... is this just a cut/paste issue?

Comment: I removed all the <table> and <tr>,<td> code and it doesn't make a difference. I am thinking at this point it has something to do with missing jar files when I build the war. This would explain why it works locally, but not when deployed.

Comment: You say you are getting a npe.  Where?  What is the stack trace?

Comment: @chrislovecnm I have updated my original question to include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with Glassfish 3.1.2. I found a [Tweet](http://twitter.com/glen_a_smith/statuses/213539806519623682) about my issue this morning which led me to this [JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18444)

Replacing the web-core.jar file fixed the problem for me. For a proof of concept I downloaded Glassfish 3.1.1 and ran my app on that version with no issues. Thus all things point to 3.1.2 being the root cause of my problem. Not anything in my app.